# Why does my calculated SNR have so much variance?

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, snr

I am running a SNR test for a real system as part of a final system test. There is real noise. The noise is calculated as the ratio between two measurements.

I noticed however that my SNR value is actually quite noisy and all over the place. For example, I have a minimum target of $8000$ for my SNR, but after running the SNR test several hundred times I get a messy distribution of SNR values, like $7500$ with a standard deviation of $600$.

Comment: Any chance you could say how you compute SNR and also show the distribution?

Comment: Usually SNR is in dB.  Is this a real system with real noise, or a computer simulation / matlab model?

Comment: @IanJ it's a real system with real noise.

Comment: @EdV for SNR, take two measurements and take their difference to be the noise. The distribution is as described, over 230 SNR tests it was ~7500 with ~600 standard deviation, although the histogram was not exactly smooth with small bins but it was relatively normal with larger bins.

Comment: @jreese cold you please **edit** your question, to include that information, and if you can, please put it into formulas – your wording is kinda "squishy" around the edges, and I'd like to avoid misunderstanding you.

Comment: I have not seen SNR computed as you do. In my field (analytical chemistry), we usually define SNR as something like (sample mean of N measurements) divided by (sample standard deviation of those N measurements). Or square that ratio for a power SNR. Of course, there are other possibilities. But without knowing anything about your measurements, I don’t see what can be said.

Comment: @Ed V if you repeat your SNR measurements and calculation do you get the same SNR value?

Comment: No, because SNRs are random variates. For example, if I obtain N independent random samples from a normal, i.e., Gaussian, distribution, then the sample mean is normally distributed, the sample standard deviation is chi distributed, and the SNR is distributed as the non-central t distribution with N-1 degrees of freedom. At low degrees of freedom, the SNR distribution is quite tailed. For your SNR scenario, everything comes down to exactly what distribution are you sampling when you get your signal?